# Ubuntu --- php composer.phar install runs slow

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

Memory available : 1 GB free

while trying to install the composer it takes time than usual more than 12 minutes.

php composer.phar install

any idea ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this question belongs to SO. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe your computer is just slow?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! it is because of the mounted partition ( amazon EFS ) had some issue, composer install went well with own partition.